# should abstract class return same type as expected implemented method?

Tags: python, abstract-class, signature

I am using Python `abc` package to declare abstract classes. When I define an abstract method, should I return an empty object with same type as expected or simply `pass`?[image]

MWE:

```
import abc


class A(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def method_1(self):
        """
        This abstract method should return a list
        """
        pass

    def method_2(self):
        list_output_method_1 = self.method_1()
        for x in list_output_method_1:
            pass
```

Doing so, PyCharm warns me in `method_2` about non iterable `list_output_method_1`.

Should I put a `return []` in `method_1` instead?

Comment: Why not try it and see what it does?

Comment: I don't see such complaints from PyCharm when actually fixing the code (e.g. adding missing `self` and proper indentation).

Comment: I get `Expected 'collections.Iterable', got 'None' instead` which makes sense to me. I have fixed the indentation and added a screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your docstring in method1 by setting the return type to list.

```
import abc

class A(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def method_1(self):
        """
        This abstract method should return a list
        :rtype: list
        """
        pass

    def method_2(self):
        list_output_method_1 = self.method_1()
        for x in list_output_method_1:
            pass
```

Comment: good for the inspection. But what about the best practice? which one is better?

Comment: I think that the combination of "pass" and a proper docstring is cleaner than returning an empty list

Comment: You should probably `raise NotImplementedError` instead of `pass`.